# Real time timer task on Android

Tags: android, audio, timer

is it possible to create under Android a real time (timer) task?
I need a high performance timer which runs every **20 ms** (without pause).

My Use-Case: Create an audio handler which puts every 20 ms an audio packet into the audio buffer. The audio data will be received in an UDP socket.

I used and testet different timer implemenations.
For example: ScheduledExecutorService, Timer/TimerTask, Handler, pure Loop (with Thread.Sleep), CountDownTimer. 
No of this solutions works well for me :(

Example dummy implementations with ScheduledExecutorService and Timer/TimerTask (totally easy, see this code):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable()
{
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
            // TODO here is my timer code
     }
}, 0, 20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask()
{
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
           // TODO own Code here
     }
}, 0, 20);
```

My problem is:

Number1: No real time guarantee, my timer will be paused sometimes for 100-200 ms (IMHO the garbage collection or other OS services ...)

Number2: If my timer is in foreground, it works very well (except problem #1), but if my App is in background, the timer interval will be increased to 60 ms (not 20ms)

I've tested it on different android versions (5.x, 6.x, 7.x), on Marshmallow it sometimes works (maybe it depend on vendor driver?)
Some ideas? Or is that not possible under Android?

Comment: android is not [rtos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), so: mission impossible

Comment: But Android can do it better using NDK. You can do something real-time on separate thread on powerful dedicated device.

Comment: @Qamar: What do you mean in detail with the NDK? I read something about better performance with the NDK, but not about RT features.

Comment: @pskink: almost realtime would be also enough, but my timer will be increased from 20ms to 60ms (in background mode). IMHO that's unbelievable.

Comment: Have you tried this in single separate thread class with `while(isRunning){ if (diff > 20ms then taskFun() else continue;}  ` with `Thread.MAX_PRIORITY`

Comment: Yes, I tried it with:
`Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO)`

Comment: ok did you try to use streaming `android.media.AudioTrack` with blocking `write()` methods?

Comment: Yes, tried it now, without success. 
If the app is moved to Background, the timer interval will be increased.

`audioTrack.write(silence, 0, silence.length);`

Comment: i am assuming you are using a `while` loop when calling `audioTrack.write` in a background thread? you dont need any time interval: just call `write()` in a loop - it will be blocked so you dont need to control any time when you call it

Comment: I used this Code in a endless while loop:
`audioTrack.write(silence, 0, silence.length)`

Comment: @pskink: Amazing! Your idea seems to work in a frist prototype. Great!

Comment: That's really cool and solves my problem #2 (see above).

Comment: so it was typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ;-)

Comment: @Tim also notice my telepathy skills that you were using `AudioTrack` already ;-)

Comment: @pskink: LoL ... Yes, I use `AudioTrack` for this stuff.

Comment: Have you some ideas for the other Problem? (real time guarantee, my timer will be paused sometimes for 100-200 ms)

Comment: wait, so `That's really cool and solves my problem #2 ` is not true?

Comment: Yes, problem #2 is solved with your approach, but not #1

Comment: I have always the problem that my thread is sometimes paused for 100-200 ms (IMHO from the OS framework or the GC)

Comment: Some ideas for the breaks?

Comment: Another question: the blocked method `AudioTrack.write()` takes mostly exact 20 ms, what's the reason for this time? Is that intentional or coincidental?